# Make a basic timer for android?

Tags: java, android, xml, timer, android-edittext

I have a `main.xml` layout set up with boxes to set times for a workout and you will be alerted when the time runs out for each. You just press start button to start the timers. How can I make it so when you type in the time and press start it atully starts timing and alerts you?

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Warm-Up" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal" >
</EditText>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Fast" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Recovery" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal" >
</EditText>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView6"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Times" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView7"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Cool-Down" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText5"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Start" />
```

Comment: what have you tried?  Your xml is going to have almost nothing to do with it.

Comment: I just don't know where to start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 new CountDownTimer(timeToBlow, timeToTick) {

 public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
     Log.d(TAG,"About to blow!!!");
 }

 public void onFinish() {
     Log.d(TAG,"BOOM!");
 }
}.start();
```

Just replace timeToBlow with the time that you get from your text fields, and timeToTick with any time that you want.

[Source](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html)

Answer (score -1):

Here is a basic example of a java timer that I found by simply searching google.
[http://www.gammelsaeter.com/programming/simple-timer-example-in-java/](http://Java%20Timer%20example)

Grab the user input from your textbox and use it to set the delay time. As far as your alerts, you are going to have to fire something from the background thread as soon as the timer ends.